# How to properly setup/record the Google Ads conversion tracking for subscription model after trial period?

Tags: google-pixel, conversion-tracking, bubble.io

Please help me to find a logic way to track/record conversions after an trial period for active subscriptions.

I have website app builder on bubble.io, i have google conversion setup on google ads and added with GTM on my website at moment the conversion are fired on thank you page when customer star an trial.
But i need it to fire only when subscriptions are paid and activated is it possible ?

At moment i am tried stripe webhook are connected to change status on customer DB for active subscription, with change of active status i have workflow to trigger javascript for fire google conversion tag thought GTM and it fires, but I do not understand if conversion will register, because customer are not on my website (to get cookies from customer browser) in this case the tracking will not recorded conversion right ?

Thanks you
Best Regards